# Ubuntu 12.04 vs Ubuntu 14.04 login after blank screen

Tags: 12.04, 14.04, login

I can login to locked user account in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS by typing the password straight away from the black screen, believing the cursor is on the password box, and it does login!. When I do the same in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, typing the password straight away from locked black screen, the first character of the password is not typed in the password box, but the subsequent characters are typed in. Why is this so? Just a silly question :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> and login into the shell.
2. Now run

   ```
   ls -lah
   ```
3. If in the output the line

   ```
   -rw-------  1 root root   53 Nov 29 10:19` .Xauthority
   ```

   - then you need to run

     ```
     chown "$USER:" .Xauthority
     ```

     and try logging in.
   - Else, do

     ```
     ls -ld /tmp
     ```

     Check for the first 10 letters in the left: they should read exactly so: `drwxrwxrwt`.

     ```
     drwxrwxrwt 15 root root 4096 Nov 30 04:17 /tmp
     ```

     Else, you need to run

     ```
     sudo chmod 1777 /tmp
     ```

     and check again.
   - If not both, I'd recommend you either

     ```
     dpkg-reconfigure lightdm
     ```

     or uninstall, reinstall it.
4. Now press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd> until you reach the login screen again, and restart.